# Javascript float compared to C# float

Tags: c#, javascript, data-structures, floating-point

just simple question about JS/C# floats. I am making multiplayer game and normally have to synchronize stuff between client and server. Now the question, are C# floats and Javascript floats same data type? Like, can I send one to another and it will understand each other. I will send floats with scientific notations because I think this way it will be the shortest and most precise. Unless you guys have any other ideas :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A [C# `double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/678hzkk9.aspx) and a [JavaScript `Number`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.19) are the same thing, both are double-precision (64-bit) [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) binary floating point numbers ("binary64"). (A [C# `float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1e65aza.aspx) is just single-precision [32-bit, "binary32"], so if you want the same thing JavaScript has, use `double`, not `float`.)

---

Side note: Although they're the same number type, their respective "to string" operations are slightly different. For instance, given the number `0.87090686143883822` (which is really `0.8709068614388382201241256552748382091522216796875`, the nearest value IEEE-754 binary64 can hold), the "to string" operation from C#, JavaScript, and Java (which also uses binary64 for its `double`) are:

```
0.870906861438838   - C#'s ToString()
0.87090686143883822 - C#'s ToString("R")
0.8709068614388382  - JavaScript's toString()
0.8709068614388382  - Java's String.valueOf(double)
```

I don't know the rules for C#, but JavaScript and Java both default to including only as many digits as are required to distinguish the number from its nearest representable neighbor. C#'s `ToString()` doesn't do that (`0.870906861438838` converts to `0.870906861438838`, precisely, losing the remaining `0.0000000000000002201241256552748382091522216796875`). C#'s `ToString("R")` includes an unnecessary additional digit.

Comment: Oh I see, Javascript actuals "float" is double a.k.a 64-bit float.
Thanks, this means I will need to use double in C#. No problem!

Thanks for clear answer!

Comment: @KoBi: JavaScript doesn't have `float` or `int` or `long` at all. It has just one number type, `Number`, which is a 64-bit IEEE-754 number.

Comment: Well that is why I asked, I was somehow sure that JS had 32bit floats for var numbers.

Comment: @KoBi: Nope. :-) It does have some mathematical operations (bitwise operators, for instance), that temporarily convert the numbers to a 32-bit integer format for the duration of the operation, but other than that, things are always floating point.

Comment: One thing to note is while C# doubles and JavaScript Numbers are the same their `.ToString`/`toString()` are not. Ex, compare the string representation of `0.87090686143883822` in both, and with both .ToString() and .ToString("R") C# will give you a different value from JavaScript. This might not cause any problems, or it might if you roundtrip any values and expect them their string representations to be identical.

Comment: @yeerk - That's a good thing to flag up, thanks! I've updated the answer. I guess the take-away is that when serializing doubles in C#, be sure to use `.ToString("R")`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I will send floats with scientific notations

Why not send data using JSON? It works rather well and decouples you from having to invent a new transport format.

Comment: It is akward to work with JSON in C#, also it adds additional overhead on both server & client. I tried to work with JSON and I gave up. Yes, it would have benefits, if game would be big. But this is just simple online snakes, so you can imagine the new transport format is just simple string tokenizing and parsing :)